# how to send packet with protocol tslv1 in php

Tags: php, packet-sniffers

I am trying to send a test packet via PHP but it does not work, please see the below code:

```
$str = "..H..u$.......E.\r\n";
$str .= ".i..@.@.......n.\r\n";
$str .= "...........]X...\r\n";
$str .= ".i...........e a\r\n";
$str .= ".:....0....e.4.\\\r\n";
$str .= ".t......n{._...~\r\n";
$str .= "0.x..{........K:\r\n";
$str .= "..<./H.\r\n";

$fp = stream_socket_client("sslv3://110.164.180.167:443", $errno, $errstr);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, $str);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

The error produced is below:

[image: image of error]

Here is a wireshark capture of the data:

[image: packet sniff by wireshark]